# useState in React Native get data of previous state

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I have one state

```
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
```

And 2 useEffects that call in parallel when component renders

```
     useEffect(() => {
       socket.on("message",()=>{
         console.log(data)
       })
     }, [socket])

    useEffect(() => {
       const res = getDataFromServer()
       setData(res.data)
     }, [isLoading])
```

2nd useEffect get data from server and set state but when socket arrive in first useEffect data is on initial state that is empty. How can I get updated state data in first useEffect when socket arrives. If I set data as dependency to first useEffect then socket event is reinitialized and callback is calling multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a function in useEffect to clean unnecessary handlers / event listeners.

[Effects with Cleanup - React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

In this function you can use the [offAny method of socket.io client](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#socket-offAny-listener) to remove previous listener.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const currentListener = socket.on("message",()=>{
    console.log(data)
  });

  return () => {
    socket.offAny(currentListener);
  };
}, [socket, data]);
```

Comment: @rana_sadam I've never used mqtt but if it has a way to remove an event listener (it most likely has) then it will work

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // This effect only executes on the initial render so that we aren't setting up the socket repeatedly.
    socket.on("message",()=>{
         console.log(data);
    })
    return () => {
      socket.off('message',() => {});
    }
  }, []);
```